# How to login to Google Maps in Android Auto, if I am already logged to my account in the system?

Tags: google-account, google-maps, 8.0-oreo, motorola-moto-e, motorola-moto-e4

**tl;dr** *I cannot use saved destinations when using Google Maps through Android Auto, because I always see a message that I must login to Google Maps first. I am logged into my Google account in both system and every other Google-like apps. Only with Google Maps there seems to be a problem. Is there any fix for that?*

---

I was more than sure that when I have an Android phone, not rooted etc., where I am logged in (system wide) to an active Google account then I am also logged in to that account in any Google-related app, including Gmail, Calendar, Contacts etc.

Yet, when I plugged my Motorola Moto E4 to my Toyota Aygo and started using Android Auto with Google Maps, this turned out to be not true.

When selecting new destination address, I can:

- Type it manually
- Pick it from Google Calendar (I am logged in there and see my account's events)
- Select one of the latest or
- Browse by a category.

But I cannot use one of the saved ones (i.e. starred), because I am always hitting the wall with message saying that I must login to Google Maps first.

Here is a screenshot (in Polish, but it does the job):

[image]

How should I proceed in this situation?

Answer (score 1):

The described situation seems to be a bug in Android Auto.

It is true that you cannot use Google Maps app without being logged in to your account. But, in this particular situation it turned out that user was and wasn't logged in in the same time. Or was semi-logged in.

Google Maps worked normally, but when opened up on the phone (not on car's display) there was a strange user-like icon in the right up corner, instead of actual user's avatar. Tapping that icon (opening user menu) immediately changed it into actual user's avatar (no actual re-login was needed). Right after that all user-related features (like saved places) started to work in Google Maps running in connected car mode.